# SIM7600E-H with ATMEGA328-P for IZAT & LTE Functionality

Tags: gps, arduino-uno, lte

I am working on interfacing of SIM7600E-H (A GPS + LTE Module) with Arduino UNO over UART using AT Commands. The high-level plan is to acquire longitude and latitude using IZAT feature and transmit them over LTE to data-server.

Development Board: Arduino UNO with UART using `<SoftwareSerial.h>`

First, I am getting GPS data using IZAT GPS feature, the acquired data is then bifurcated to get actual longitude and latitude position. Then, creating a data-string comprises POST request and acquired longitude & latitude data. The data-string is of 217 bytes. This data-string is then transferred to SIM7600E-H using command AT+CIPSEND and a terminator - 0x1A. Now, as per AT command set manual, +CIPSEND command should return the received bytes, but it is acknowledging with 0,2,2 instead of 0,217,217. Now, If we follow the same steps for Standalone GPS instead of IZAT GPS then we are getting successful acknowledgment with 0,217,217 and data is also getting posted on data-server.

Further tested, with IZAT GPS feature enabled, I found out that I am able to transmit around 150 bytes only, when using +CIPSEND command. If I am adding some more bytes then it is again acknowledging with 0,2,2.

Prior doubt was if `<SoftwareSerial.h>` is creating this problem or not?
So, I tried with `<AltSoftSerial.h>` and even with Hardware serial on DIO 0 & 1. But problem still persists.

So, I facing this kind of issue with +CIPSEND command when enabling IZAT GPS feature.

Serial monitor outputs when using IZAT GPS and Standalone GPS separately:

[image]